# AS3 removeChild and collisions : issue

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, removechild

I'm working in a little shooting game with Flash and AS3. I'm still beginning for using Class documents, but I managed to understand thanks to tutorials.
So here's how it works :
I used the HitTestObject when the Enemy MovieClip hits a bullet, shot by the user :

```
//checking if it is touching any bullets
//we will have to run a for loop because there will be multiple bullets
for(var i:int = 0;i<_root.bulletContainer.numChildren;i++){
    //numChildren is just the amount of movieclips within
    //the bulletContainer.
//we define a variable that will be the bullet that we are currently
//hit testing.
var bulletTarget:MovieClip = _root.bulletContainer.getChildAt(i);

//now we hit test

if(hitTestObject(bulletTarget)){
    hit++;
    if(hit==4)
    {
    gotoAndPlay(4); //the Enemy MC is removed after 4 hits(parent.removeChild(this))
    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, eFrame);
    //the Bullet MC is removed with its Listeners
    _root.bulletContainer.removeChild(bulletTarget);
    bulletTarget.removeListeners();
    }

    if(hit<4)
    {
    gotoAndPlay(2);
    _root.bulletContainer.removeChild(bulletTarget);
    bulletTarget.removeListeners();

    }
    if(hit > 4)
    {
    _root.bulletContainer.removeChild(bulletTarget);
    bulletTarget.removeListeners();
        hit = 0;
    }
}
}
```

So after 4 hits, it is completely removed from the screen.
The eFrame function remove the Enemy MC if it goes off the stage :

```
    private function eFrame (event:Event):void{
        x+=speed;
        if(this.x > stage.stageWidth + 50){
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, eFrame);
            _root.removeChild(this);
    }
}
```

I also put a command that detects collisions between the Enemy MC and the Player (that I gave the "craft" instance name) :

```
if(hitTestPoint(_root.craft.x -203.25, _root.craft.y - 44.9, collide)) 
    {
       _root.dmg.width+=8;//reduce the life bar
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, eFrame); 
        gotoAndPlay(4); 
    }
    if(hitTestPoint(_root.craft.x -210.6, _root.craft.y - 32.9, collide))
    {
       _root.dmg.width+=8;
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, eFrame);
        gotoAndPlay(4);

    }
    if(hitTestPoint(_root.craft.x -210.6, _root.craft.y - 6, collide))
    {
       _root.dmg.width+=8;
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, eFrame);
        gotoAndPlay(4);
    }
    if(hitTestPoint(_root.craft.x -211.4, _root.craft.y + 20, collide))
    {
       _root.dmg.width+=8;
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, eFrame);
        gotoAndPlay(4);
    }
...//There is a lot of other points with the same results...
```

So the Enemy MC is also removed if it hits the craft MC (Player). But I encountered an issue : when the Enemy MC is hit (4 times by the Bullet movieclips "shot" by the user which removes it) **but also *collided*** by the player, *it is not removed as it ought to be...* 
It is instead still displayed on the screen, and is static : it can't be hit neither by a bullet MC, neither by the player MC...

I think this is because of the `parent.removeChild(this)` executed from `gotoAndPlay(4)` of the Enemy MC, which causes that issue : it is executed **a twice** (because the Enemy MC is *destroyed by the Bullet MC AND by the Player*)... 
Anyone has an idea to solve that double execution of `removeChild` ? 
If you want to have more info, you can download the source :
https://www.dropbox.com/s/wvl116wjqpu69d0/shoot_aircraft%20game.zip?dl=0

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Didn't read the whole thing but this smells like a bad case of the coding while switching frames in the main timeline. Best to avoid that practice all together. In my opinion, the main timeline is for animators, not programmers.

Comment: Hello, all the code that I wrote there is in an Actionscript Class document. Only the `parent.removeChild(this)` is on the **MovieClip's timeline...**

Comment: you could try adding a conditional check like if (enemy) {remove enemy} so it doesn't try to remove it if the other collision already did.

Comment: Hi I added a check like `if(hit!=4)` before the collisions check...But I got the same problem, despite of the fact that the user shots 4 times, the collision with the player is still functional... Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hit!=4 won't work. Because hit=4.

Comment: That's weird... I also tried with `if(hit<4)` with the same problem...

Comment: What is on frame 4?

Comment: Shouldn't you be calling remove child on the ship to enemy collision?

Comment: In other words, what is supposed to happen to the enemy when it hits the craft? RemoveChild? Play animation on frame 4? Both? Is frame 4 just empty?

Comment: It plays the Movieclip from the fourth frame, and at the end, it executes the `parent.removeChild(this)` line. It does have the same thing when it hits the player...

Comment: Not getting any error messages?

Comment: No error messages...

Comment: Does the enemy freeze in place? Or keep running around doing his thing? And it only happens when he gets hit by a bullet during collision with the ship?

Comment: It freezes in place only when it hits both the ship and four times the bullet.

Comment: So does that mean the 4th bullet has to be hitting the enemy during the 4 frames of animation to cause this bug?

Comment: Hmm it hits the enemy, before playing the fourth frame... Otherwise when it freezes, I wanted to say that it stops moving and keep playing the animation when it moves (before the 4th frame)...

Comment: What is the enemy's parent? The stage? A container?

Comment: This is the stage.

Comment: Ok. I would try this next: put your animation inside a container and remove the container. So on frame 4 it could say parent.parent.removeChild(this.parent)

Answer (score 0):

Put your enemy inside of a container (could be just a Sprite object) and on the 4th frame of the animation call

`parent.parent.removeChild(this.parent);`

You'll have to change a few of your enemy movement lines of code maybe but you can figure that out.

Basically the idea is to hide the animation inside of a non animating Sprite. Changing frames mid code screws things up, unless it's nested deeper than the object that is being called on. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: I don't know if I did exactly what you said but I created an empty Movieclip as container and put the enemy Movieclip inside it. I wrote your code inside (in the enemy Movieclip not in the container) and at the fourth frame when it finishes the animation I put your code line. I called the enemy Movieclip inside the container with an "e" instance name. On the Class document, for accessing to the Movieclip inside the container I wrote this : `["e"].gotoAndPlay(4);` And it doesn't work : the Movieclip now freezes when it is destroyed by the player without being destroyed by the collision...

Comment: There's only one enemy? It has an instance name called "e"?

Comment: When it is inside of the container, yes.

Comment: What do you mean " when it is inside the container"? Isn't it inside the container from the moment of its creation?

Comment: Yes it is, with an "e" instance name.

Comment: I don't know about your instance name use. I don't call objects that way. I just assign a variable to that instance when it is created and then reference the variable. Are you not creating the enemy in AS3?

Comment: Hmm no I'm sorry, I didn't know that you were doing on this way by assigning variables. I guess that I have to do it by variables too  : I only used AS3 for creating enemies without the container (I didn't assigned a variable inside the container) Sorry If I wasted your time... We'll continue another time because it's midnight in Paris I will go to sleep : thank you a lot for your help.

Comment: Ok. I'll try to look at it this weekend if I have time. Maybe next week I'll download your file and play around with it.

Comment: Thank you again. I tested your idea : inside the container I assigned the Enemy Movieclip like that : `var e: Enemy = new Enemy(); addChild(e);` At the fourth frame of this Movieclip I typed your code, and so in the Class document I wrote `e.gotoAndPlay(4);`. I launched the swf file, and It has the same issue as the beginning : the container Movieclip executes the enemy's animation correctly, but it freezes again when it collides the player and removed by the bullet Movieclips..

Comment: And if you just get rid of the animation all together it works fine?

Comment: What do you mean ? If it only executes `parent.parent.removeChild(this)` at the fourth frame, and not the entire animation from frame 4 ?

Comment: Hmm I tested on a hundreds of enemies, and it looks like it works fine : when I put your code only on frame 4 and not at the end of its animation, none of the movieclips are freezing.

Comment: I tested again and now I have this error : 'TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. at       Enemy/eFrame. It shows the line where I wrote the `if(hit<4)` check  at the `if(hitTestObject(bulletTarget))` check...I don't know why...

Comment: More precisely at the `_root.bulletContainer.removeChild(bulletTarget);` line. Sorry if I bother you...

Comment: Thank you again, I can wait if you want.

Comment: You know what ? You can check another time on my problem if you want, because I'll go to sleep. It can be tomorrow, or in two days or more : anytime when you're free. Thank you very much for your assistance.